# Database migration in sqlcipher

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I used sqlcipher 3.* to encrypt my database. It work very well; But now I want to migrate to new database ( Version 2 ).When I change database version, open database do not work and can not open previous database.

```
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH,DB_PASS, null);
```

Exception occur in this line in class `SQLiteDatabase`

```
this.dbopen(this.mPath, this.mFlags);
```

`mFlags` does not value.

The second problem, is database version. always return 0 .
My current sqlcipher's version is 3.3.1-2 that add it from `Maven`.
I add `icudt46l.zip` to `assets` folder.
and add `commons-codec.jar` , `quava-r09.jar` and `sqlcipher-javadoc.jar` to `libs` folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if the version of the database is not being set.  You can either do this manually with `setVersion(…)` and `getVersion()` from your `SQLiteDatabase` instance, or you would be required to provide a value if you are subclassing `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  We have a [test](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/VerifyOnUpgradeIsCalledTest.java) that verifies the `onUpgrade(…)` function is called once the version number changes with a `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass.